# Make a Javascript array into JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json

I've tried searching google and nothing is clear, plus you guys are way faster and correct.

I have an array as follows:

```
var bannertext = new Array();
bannertext[1] = "ladidadi";
bannertext[2] = "blahblahblahblah";
bannertext[3] = "oooaaaaooooaaa";
```

How do I turn the `bannertext` array into a JSON encoded array so that I can send it to a PHP page and break it down using the `json_decode` function, and then how do I access the individual variables?

EDIT: Thanks to Gazler for that first part! My PHP page looks like this:

```
$bannertext = $_GET['bannertext'];
$banner = json_decode($bannertext);
```

How do I access each of those strings now? LIke `echo $banner[1];` and so on?

Answer (score 2):

You use JSON.stringify() however in IE you will need to include the [json2](http://www.json.org/js.html) library as IE has no native JSON parsing.

```
var bannertext = new Array();
bannertext[1] = "ladidadi";
bannertext[2] = "blahblahblahblah";
bannertext[3] = "oooaaaaooooaaa";
console.log(JSON.stringify(bannertext));
```

As an aside, you can instantiate an array using the array literal syntax.

```
var bannertext = [];
```

[Here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2151-when-to-use-the-array-literal-notation-in-javascript/) is a blog post explaining the difference.

Comment: IE 8+ brings [native support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/10/native-json-in-ie8.aspx) for it; but still more-or-less true.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify:

```
JSON.stringify(bannertext);
```

[**Older browsers**](http://caniuse.com/#search=jSON), IE7 and below, require an external library [**Json2 Free CDN**](http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js)